# Angular2 how to set radio button as checked with a default value

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to Angular2, I have a radio group and I am trying to bind it using [(ngModel)] to entity person.testBoolean so that I can save it in the database. I want to set a default value as selected and I have seen few examples and found that they set the default value to [(ngModel)] but in my case I want to bind it to my entity hence I cannot use [(ngModel)]. Can anybody advise alternative options. checked = idx does not work.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="radioboolean">Boolean: </label>
    <div *ngFor="let entry of entries; let idx = index" class="radio-inline" >
       <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="person.testBoolean" name="radiogroup" [checked]="idx === 1" [value]="entry.id" />{{ entry.description }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Ts code:

```
 entries = [
              {id: 1, description: 'True' },
              {id: 2,description: 'False'},
              {id: 3,description: 'Undefined'}
           ];
```

Person is my entity:

```
export interface IPerson {

    id: string;
    name: string;
    testNumber: number | null;
    testDatetime: Date | null;
    testBoolean: boolean | null;
    // Refs to parent entities
    team: ITeam;
    teamId: string;

};
```

Comment: yes, that's right we can directly use the id column but it did not work :-( , default radio button is still not selected/checked

Answer (score 6):

You can use the id of entry like this: `[checked]="entry.id === 1"`

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of entries; let idx = index" class="radio-inline" >
                <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="person.testBoolean" name="radiogroup" [checked]="entry.id === 1" [value]="entry.id" />{{ entry.description }}
            </div>
```

Comment: yes, that's right we can directly use the id column but it did not work :-( , default radio button is still not selected/checked

Comment: Tried `[checked]="entry.id === default"`? Where default = `this.default` in component.

Comment: Hi Swoox, Thanks, I tried as above but for some reason "this.default" is set to undefined hence default radio buttons is not selected.          
  Typescript file                                                                               
  `default: 3;`

    `entries = [{ id: 1, description: 'True' },{ id: 2, description: 'False' },`
        `{ id: 3, description: 'Undefined' }]; `                                                                                                                       `[checked]="entry.id === default"  `

Comment: With default I meany make a value on your component above constructor `private defaullt: any`. then where you set your entries say `this.default = 1`. So the checkbox with entry id 1 will be checked.

Comment: Do you mean like this?   Previously I declared a variable within the class , above the constructor. Do you mean declare within the constructor:                                                                                  `constructor(private defaultradio: any) { }`

    `ngOnInit() {`
        `this.defaultradio = 1; .....`

Comment: `private defaullt: any`
 `constructor() { }`

Comment: Now the console.log display value 1 instead of undefined but still the default radio button is not selected.                                                                   
`private defaultradio: any;`                                                                                     `[checked]="entry.id === defaultradio"   `

Comment: entry.id is a number of a string? Equal to defaultradio string or number?

Comment: entry.id is a number from the above code snippet, defaultradio is type any but I changed to number now. still it does not select the radio button.

Comment: Then I don't know it either gl.

Answer (score 4):

If you always want the first item to be selected you can use.

In your loop, `*ngFor="let entry of entries; let first = first;`

and in your radio button group - `[checked] = "first"`

for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of entries; let first = first; let idx = index" class="radio-inline" >
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="person.testBoolean" name="radiogroup" [checked]="first" [value]="entry.id" />{{ entry.description }}
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like charm!

Answer (score 2):

An example:
in Template file:

```
 <form [formGroup]="formGender">
        <input type="radio" value="1" [(ngModel)]="userBasicInformation.gender">
        <span class="font-size-12px font-bold">MALE</span>
        <input type="radio" value="0" [(ngModel)]="userBasicInformation.gender">
        <span class="font-size-12px font-bold">FEMALE</span>
 </form>
```

In Component.ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userBasicInformation.gender = '0';
}
```

And result, the radio button will select default at gender value = 0 (Female) as following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```js
export class ConfirmationmodalComponent implements OnInit {
  cancel_associated_session: any = false;

  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input
    class="form-check-input"
    type="radio"
    id="inlineRadio1"
    name="cancel_associated_session"
    [(ngModel)]="cancel_associated_session"
    [value]="true"
  />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">
    Yes
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input
    class="form-check-input"
    type="radio"
    id="inlineRadio2"
    name="cancel_associated_session"
    [(ngModel)]="cancel_associated_session"
    [value]="false"
  />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">
    No
  </label>
</div>
```